# Xamarin, get the time of a call then display it in a XAML page

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm trying to add a piece of code in my page to get the time of a call. In the XAML code I have a listView that displays a list of people and a searchbar to find by name, I also have a clickable label to call a defined number. I just want to find a way to display the time after the call. I just need to know how to make it possible. I can describe more my code if nessecary. My tries didn't succeeded.

The code to call :

```
 var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
            tapGestureRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                Device.OpenUri(new Uri("phone:00000000"));
            };


            Number.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);
```

XAML :

```
  <ContentPage.Content>


        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="People"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
            <ListView x:Name="lstView" BackgroundColor="Beige" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding .}"/>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>


            <Label x:Name="Number" HorizontalOptions="Center">Call</Label>

            <SearchBar x:Name="searchBar"  Placeholder="search" SearchButtonPressed="OnSearchBarButtonPressed" 
                       Text="{Binding SearchedText, Mode=TwoWay}"
           SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
            <Label x:Name="searchResults" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a DateTime property to your Person object:

```
public class Person
{
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Assign a value in your ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; } = new 
ObservableCollection<Person>();
var p = new Person();
p.DateTime = DateTime.Now
People.Add(p);
```

And bind it in your xaml:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Column="2" VerticalOptions="Center" 
HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <Label Text="{Binding DateTime}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
</StackLayout>
```